# How to include an id (or class) in an ERB element

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have this code for displaying comments on an article which uses ERB elements to fetch and display information from a database:

```
<div class="comments">
  <h4 class="comment_author">Comment by <%= comment.author_name %></h4>
  <p class="comment"><%= comment.body %></p>
</div>
```

I would like to format the comment.author_name differently, so I wanted to include an id on the second line e.g.

```
<h4 class="comment_author">Comment by <%= comment.author_name, id: "commenter" %></h4>
```

However, when I do this I get the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAWuR.png).

I have added classes and ids in the past to form elements with the
 :class => "name" syntax like so:

```
<%= f.submit 'Create Article', :class => 'create_new_article_button'%>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working here either. Is there a different way to add ids and classes to non-form ERB elements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<h4 class="comment_author", id='commenter''>Comment by <%= comment.author_name %></h4>`

Comment: Your trying to add the `id` in the wrong place. You are currently trying to add an `id` in the content of `h4` & NOT on the tag itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= comment.author_name %>` is **not a tag/element**, its just a value(string i assume) & hence you cannot add an `id` attribute to it. You could instead do

```
<h4 class="comment_author">Comment by 
   <span id="commenter"><%= comment.author_name %></span>
</h4>
```

Or give the `id="commenter"` directly to the `<h4>` tag & use that to target the `span`.

> It worked earlier because `f.submit` refers to a **submit button of a form**, meaning it was actually an HTML element & hence you could add an `id` or a `class` to it.

Comment: I didn't realise it wasn't a tag/element, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can not add an ID to a content. Instead you should add ID to the element which is wrapping your content. In your case it should be like this

```
<h4 class="comment_author" id='commenter'>Comment by <%= comment.author_name %></h4>
```

This will create h4 element with an ID 'commenter'.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing here

> I have added classes and ids in the past to form elements with the
>   :class => "name" syntax like so:
>
> <%= f.submit 'Create Article', :class => 'create_new_article_button'%>
>   But that doesn't seem to be working here either.

Form elements will receive `class` has one of it's arguments. Check the docs  [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag) . But `<%= %>` will just display the end result of ruby code in the views, but it won't add any html content to the DOM. Please read docs carefully before implementing something.